# Variable swap with and without auxiliary variable - which is faster?

Tags: c, assembly, swap

I guess you all heard of the 'swap problem'; SO is full of questions about it.
The version of the swap without use of a third variable is often considered to be faster since, well, you have one variable less. I wanted to know what was going on behind the curtains and wrote the following two programs:

```
int main () {
    int a = 9;
    int b = 5;
    int swap;

    swap = a;
    a = b;
    b = swap;

    return 0;
}
```

and the version without third variable:

```
int main () {
    int a = 9;
    int b = 5;

    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;

    return 0;
}
```

I generated the assembly code using clang and got this for the first version (that uses a third variable):

```
...
Ltmp0:
    movq   %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl   $0, %eax
    movl   $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl   $9, -8(%rbp)
    movl   $5, -12(%rbp)
    movl   -8(%rbp), %ecx
    movl   %ecx, -16(%rbp)
    movl   -12(%rbp), %ecx
    movl   %ecx, -8(%rbp)
    movl   -16(%rbp), %ecx
    movl   %ecx, -12(%rbp)
    popq   %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end0:
...
```

and this for the second version (that does not use a third variable):

```
...
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl   $0, %eax
    movl   $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl   $9, -8(%rbp)
    movl   $5, -12(%rbp)
    movl   -12(%rbp), %ecx
    movl   -8(%rbp), %edx
    xorl   %ecx, %edx
    movl   %edx, -8(%rbp)
    movl   -8(%rbp), %ecx
    movl   -12(%rbp), %edx
    xorl   %ecx, %edx
    movl   %edx, -12(%rbp)
    movl   -12(%rbp), %ecx
    movl   -8(%rbp), %edx
    xorl   %ecx, %edx
    movl   %edx, -8(%rbp)
    popq   %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end0:
...
```

The second one is longer but I don't know much about assembly code so I have no idea if that means that it is slower so I'd like to hear the opinion of someone more knowledgable about it.

**Which of the above versions of a variable swap is faster and takes less memory?**

Comment: To find out which is faster, why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to measure memory usage plus, I'm also interested in the reasons behind it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you compiled with optimizations turned on.  There's a lot of fluff in that assembly.

Comment: The XOR trick _might_ have been faster ages ago but not on modern CPUs. Just use a temporary variable and enable compiler optimizations.

Comment: It's not meaningful to try to jugde the speed of compiler generated code and leaving off optimization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at some optimised assembly. From

```
void swap_temp(int *restrict a, int *restrict b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void swap_xor(int *restrict a, int *restrict b){
    *a ^= *b;
    *b ^= *a;
    *a ^= *b;
}
```

`gcc -O3 -std=c99 -S -o swapping.s swapping.c` produced

```
    .file   "swapping.c"
.text
.p2align 4,,15
.globl swap_temp
.type   swap_temp, @function
swap_temp:
.LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
movl    (%rdi), %eax
movl    (%rsi), %edx
movl    %edx, (%rdi)
movl    %eax, (%rsi)
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
.size   swap_temp, .-swap_temp
.p2align 4,,15
.globl swap_xor
.type   swap_xor, @function
swap_xor:
.LFB1:
.cfi_startproc
movl    (%rsi), %edx
movl    (%rdi), %eax
xorl    %edx, %eax
xorl    %eax, %edx
xorl    %edx, %eax
movl    %edx, (%rsi)
movl    %eax, (%rdi)
ret
.cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
.size   swap_xor, .-swap_xor
.ident  "GCC: (SUSE Linux) 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 167585]"
.section    .comment.SUSE.OPTs,"MS",@progbits,1
.string "Ospwg"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

To me, `swap_temp` looks as efficient as can be.

Comment: Nice one, thanks for the optimization! Is this as fast/short as it gets? Btw, does it make any difference if I swap pointers instead of the variables?

Comment: I dare say that `swap_temp` is optimal. For `swap_xor`, without the `restrict` qualifiers, gcc generates one instruction less, it becomes three `movl a, b; xorl c, d` where in each op, one of the args is a register (`%eax`, always) and one a pointer dereference (`(%rsi)` or `(%rdi)`). According to my measurements, it's slower (but if the function is visible at the call site, inlining can remove the difference). Regarding the difference between swapping variables and swapping pointers, swapping variables can never be hidden, so optimisations can often eliminate it altogether.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with XOR swap trick is that it's strictly sequential. It may seem deceptively fast, but in reality, it is not. There's an instruction called `XCHG` that swaps two registers, but this can also be slower than simply using 3 `MOVs`, due to its atomic nature. The common technique with temp is an excellent choice ;)

Comment: -1 there are no sync issues with `xchg reg1, reg2`. The sync issues only arise with `xchg` with memory operands.

Comment: @Johan whoa, alrighty, good to know, thank you! :) (I fixed the answer)

Comment: You edited the answer, but its still incorrect. `XCHG reg, reg` does **not** have atomicity issues, and it therefor not slower than 3 `MOV`s. Depending on the processor XCHG may (or may not) break down into multiple micro-ops. Only `XCHG reg,[reg]` (which exchanges a reg with a memory location) is slow, because it has an implicit `LOCK` prefix attached to it. It's the `LOCK` prefix which slows it down.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of the cost imagine that every command has a cost to be performed and also the indirect addressing has its own cost.

```
movl   -12(%rbp), %ecx
```

This line will need something like a time unit for accessing the value in ecx register,
one time unit for accessing rbp, another one for applying the offset (-12) and more time 
units (let's say arbitrarily 3) for moving the value from the address stored in ecx to the 
address indicated from -12(%rbp).

If you count all the operations in every line and all line, the second method is for sure costlier than the first one.

Comment: This is true in this case, but not general, as it ignores pipelining opportunities.

Comment: Agreed, but then you have to know how to optimize your code for optimized pipelining and minimizing branching. I think it's easier for our friend to start with minimizing unnecessary referencing and excessive commands and then go to more advanced techniques.