# Why is using a third variable faster than an addition trick?

Tags: c, optimization, fibonacci

When computing fibonacci numbers, a common method is mapping the pair of numbers `(a, b)` to `(b, a + b)` multiple times. This can usually be done by defining a third variable `c` and doing a swap. However, I realised you could do the following, avoiding the use of a third integer variable:

```
b = a + b;  // b2 = a1 + b1
a = b - a;  // a2 = b2 - a1 = b1, Ta-da!
```

I expected this to be faster than using a third variable, since in my mind this new method should only have to consider two memory locations.

So I wrote the following C programs comparing the processes. These mimic the calculation of fibonacci numbers, but rest assured I am aware that they will not calculate the correct values due to size limitations.

(Note: I realise now that it was unnecessary to make `n` a `long int`, but I will keep it as it is because that is how I first compiled it)

#### File: PlusMinus.c

```
// Using the 'b=a+b;a=b-a;' method.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long int n = 1000000; // Number of iterations.
    long int a,b;

    a = 0; b = 1;
    while (n--) {
        b = a + b;
        a = b - a;
    }

    printf("%lu\n", a);
}
```

#### File: ThirdVar.c

```
// Using the third-variable method.
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long int n = 1000000; // Number of iterations.
    long int a,b,c;

    a = 0; b = 1;
    while (n--) {
        c = a;
        a = b;
        b = b + c;
    }

    printf("%lu\n", a);
}
```

When I run the two with GCC (no optimisations enabled) I notice a consistent difference in speed:

```
$ time ./PlusMinus
14197223477820724411

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.009s
sys     0m0.002s

$ time ./ThirdVar
14197223477820724411

real    0m0.012s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.002s
```

When I run the two with GCC with `-O3`, the assembly outputs are equal. (I suspect I had confirmation bias when stating that one just outperformed the other in previous edits.)

Inspecting the assembly for each, I see that `PlusMinus.s` actually has one less instruction than `ThirdVar.s`, but runs consistently slower.

#### Question

Why does this time difference occur? Not only at all, but also why is my addition/subtraction method slower contrary to my expectations?

Comment: Modern CPUs can eliminate register-register moves by just renaming the register. They cannot eliminate the arithmetic instructions (though the compiler might be able to, if you used `unsigned`).

Comment: The answer to this question is in the assembly code. Compile with `-S` to see it.

Comment: Compilers recognize a swap is going on and optimize.

Comment: MC68000 had a `SWAP` instruction for data registers already.

Comment: The 3-variable version can execute all those instructions in parallel. In the 2-variable version both variables depend on the previous instruction.

Comment: Similar to the old-fashioned XOR method of swapping, which was to conserve memory use, not for speed. In both cases there are more memory read/writes needed than using a temporary variable. One flaw in your method is you might break the `int` limit (as in the naive implementation of the `cmp` function required by `qsort`).

Comment: There are other factors in play here as well, that may or may not have an effect on performance.  Any chance of finding it starts with the disassembly of each solution.

Comment: (1) Measuring speed of unoptimised code is a complete utter waste of time. Unoptimised code is produced to be debuggable, not to win benchmarks. (2) There is no difference when optimisations are on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable swap with and without auxiliary variable - which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567609/variable-swap-with-and-without-auxiliary-variable-which-is-faster)

Comment: If you change that `-` to a `+`, you're doing 2 iterations at once without any kind of swap, not even a fast swap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does this time difference occur?

There is no time difference when compiled with optimizations (under recent versions of gcc and clang). For instance, gcc 8.1 for x86_64 compiles both to:

[<kbd>Live at Godbolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/g/qS93hV)

```
.LC0:
        .string "%lu\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     eax, 1000000
        mov     esi, 1
        mov     edx, 0
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        mov     rsi, rcx
.L2:
        lea     rcx, [rdx+rsi]
        mov     rdx, rsi
        sub     rax, 1
        jne     .L3
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

> Not only at all, but also why is my addition/subtraction method slower contrary to my expectations?

Adding and subtracting could be slower than just moving. However, in most architectures (e.g. a x86 CPU), it is basically the same (1 cycle plus the memory latency); so this does not explain it.

The real problem is, most likely, the dependencies between the data. See:

```
b = a + b;
a = b - a;
```

To compute the second line, you have to have finished computing the value of the first. If the compiler uses the expressions as they are (which is the case under `-O0`), that is what the CPU will see.

In your second example, however:

```
c = a;
a = b;
b = b + c;
```

You can compute both the new `a` and `b` at the same time, since they do not depend on each other. And, in a modern processor, those operations can actually be computed in parallel. Or, putting it another way, you are not "stopping" the processor by making it wait on a previous result. This is called [Instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the optimised assembly output for both were equal; I just updated the question as you posted this, I think I had confirmation bias there.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi: Yeah, but the results are still independent, i.e. the two equations `a = b`, `b = b + a` can be done in parallel. In any case, the explanation is trying to be high-level / introductory. To really analyze what is going on, we would need to take into account register renaming, OoO execution, etc. of a particular CPU. A simple example: memory accesses here are irrelevant (even if present in the assembly), because they fit in a single line of cache. Another example: gcc uses `rax` all the time, but the CPU might not be using the same real register, so dependencies can be removed.